# MySQL how to add all of a column together where pid= X

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Just wondering what would be the best way of adding all the values in a column together where the pid=$pid in a column.

Here's some sample code of what I'm using:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT pid, reputation FROM reputation WHERE pid=\"{$post['pid']}\"");

while($rep = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $rep['reputation'];
}
```

That works fine, but when more than one row exists where the pid=X I need the reputation column on those rows to add together and output the result.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT pid, SUM(reputation) totalReputation
FROM reputation 
WHERE pid = 0
GROUP BY pid
```

in php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT pid, SUM(reputation) totalReputation
                      FROM reputation 
                      WHERE pid = " .$post['pid'] ."
                      GROUP BY pid");
```

and fetch the alias

```
echo $rep['totalReputation'];
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks @JW. I've sanitized the input earlier on in the script. It's adding the total of the column fine now but it's only showing the first PID, not the others. How can I loop through each one? I'm using:     while($rep = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo $rep['totalReputation'];
    }

Comment: did you have `WHERE pid = x` in your query?

Comment: Yeah, my query is: `SELECT pid, SUM(reputation) totalReputation
                      FROM mybb_reputation 
                      WHERE pid = ".$post['pid']."
                      GROUP BY pid`              Thanks :)

Comment: try removing the `WHERE` cluase

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks a load, @JW. :)

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as `accepted` by clicking the white check mark (*around 15 mins to an hour later*). This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. [*How does accepting an answer work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(reputation) as rep FROM reputation WHERE pid=\"{$post['pid']}\"");

while($rep = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $rep['rep'];
}
```

**NOTE: You should not use mysql_* extension since they are now deprecated.**

Comment: echo $rep['reputation']; should be echo $rep['SUM(reputation)'];